# How can I scroll with selenium if I already follow a user?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to make an auttomat instagram follow script with selenium and python but I am a little stuck. I ve searched all around the internet but nothing clear for me
I want to enter on a user followers and click follow on all followers. How I make the system to scroll down if I am already following the user. I tried like this but I got this error: element click intercepted

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time, urllib.request
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"F:\132\instagram\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Accept All"]')\
  .click()
sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//input[@name=\"username\"]"))\
    .send_keys(("#"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//input[@name=\"password\"]"))\
    .send_keys(("#"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')\
    .click()
sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]')\
  .click()
sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]')\
  .click()
  #searchbox
time.sleep(5)
searchbox=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='Search']")
searchbox.clear()
searchbox.send_keys("delianomad")
time.sleep(5)
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(6)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("followers").click()
buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Follow']")    
scroll = 0
sleep(10)
fBody  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")   
for btn in buttons:
     if btn.text == 'Follow':
         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
         sleep(60)
     else :
         driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
   
print("Sesiune terminata")
```

Comment: I don t get the idea with that locator, what should i edit in my code?

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code does not make sense:

```
buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Follow']")    
scroll = 0
sleep(10)
fBody  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")   
for btn in buttons:
     if btn.text == 'Follow':
         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
         sleep(60)
     else :
         driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
```

Please be aware, that first you are getting all elements with text 'Follow' to `buttons`, then you check if text of each element is in fact equal to `Follow`. Try to find different locator for those buttons, e.g.

```
//div[@aria-label='Followers']//ul//button
```

with this, you will get list of buttons (with and without 'Follow' text), then you can perform your actions depending if text equals 'Follow'.

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll to the element with the following code given below.

```
    public static void scrollElement(WebElement element) {
    Coordinates cor = ((Locatable) element).getCoordinates();
    cor.inViewPort();
    pause(2);
}
```